# Huge Banner Padding

Tags: html, css, padding, banner

I added a banner into a webpage, www.torontopoet.com/etsystories and now below the banner is a huge chunk of blank space before the content begins. This is the code I used for the banner:

```
<div id="banner"> 
</div>
 <style>
html,body
{ height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#banner {
background:url('.png');
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-size:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
 }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your HTML too, I really can't say anything, but...

```
#banner {
background:url('.png');
width:100%;  
height:100%; <!--- ? --->
background-size:100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
```

Are you sure you want the banner to be 100% of the height of its container?

Comment: Probably not? If I change the height to a px amount, the white space goes away but then the content can cover the banner when the browser size is distorted.

Comment: Really need to see HTML before I can say anything sensible about that...

Comment: Hi David, the website is www.torontopoet.com/etsystories

Comment: I had a quick look, but I really think you have bigger worries. Sorry. Try to get it to validate first. From what I see your content won't cover your banner, though.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I don't think the content will cover the banner but the content appears much lower than the banner, especially on a phone.

Comment: These steps I would take: validate. (https://validator.w3.org/) because nothing you do makes sense until you know the code isn't throwing a curve-ball. Then use media queries to tweak for mobile. Also consider loading times on mobile. Is your banner worth losing customers? A light version for mobile is a very good idea, imho.

Comment: Fair enough. Would there be a code to just simply override the default title so it displays something unique? @daviddylan?

Comment: For that, you'd have to look at the settings of the package that generates the code. There's ways to do it after the fact, but that's not very efficient. And if all else fails you could use css + media queries to hide it altogether.

Answer (score 0):

```
html,body
{ 
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
#banner 
{
background:url('http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hubfs/418991/realview.jpg');
width:400px;
height:251px;
display:block;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Explain how this code is going to help the OP.

Comment: if you specify correct height and width then banner background image  cover whole portion and don't have white spacing issue

Comment: **As this answer was flagged as Inappropriate.** (not an answer)  Better edit your answer and add the information how this will resolve the problem of OP. That's why I am saying this again so that this answer won't be downvoted and deleted in future by the [Moderators](http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

Comment: Please check this jsfield      https://jsfiddle.net/payal2299/1f56u4x6/4/